# how to fix it i get type error, not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

```
import urllib2
import json
import time


READ_API_KEY ="5TK6782EGPH7KTAX"
CHANNEL_ID = "907593"


while True:
    TS = urllib2.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/907593/feeds.json?api_key=5TK6782EGPH7KTAX&results=2" \
                       %(CHANNEL_ID,READ_API_KEY))

response = TS.read()
data=json.loads(response)


a = data['created_at']
b = data['field1']
c = data['field2']
print a + "    " + b + "    " + c 
time.sleep(5)   

TS.close()
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to format two values into a string that already has both of them, and doesn't have any defined places to put values. It's unclear to me why you thought that *would* work.

Comment: You are trying to format a string, without any format strings, as @jonrsharpe pointed out. Although, If `python3.6` or greater, perhaps use `f"https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/{CHANNEL_ID}/feeds.json?api_key={READ_API_KEY}&results=2"`. And you probably wanna hide those keys from public

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `urllib2.urlopen` should be

`"https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/%s/feeds.json?api_key=%s&results=2" % 
 (CHANNEL_ID,READ_API_KEY)`.

with `%s` modifier used in string formatting syntax borrowed from C.

Or use the `.format` (introduced from Python 2.6, a better option) as suggested in the comments.
Read [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples).